# Generate JSON response on server with JsonArray and single fields

Tags: php, json, server

I am trying to build a JSON response from my server side, but it is not working as expected.

It is probably something simple but, I am not so good at PHP...

The basic expected response is a JSON with a single JsonArray and some other fields, for that, the relevant piece of code is shown here:

**Sample of expected JSON response:**

```
{  
   "pageNr": 2
   "totalPages":28
   "products":[  
      {  
         "user_name":"testUser001",
         "product_ID":"4756373abdhg"
      },
      {  
         "user_name":"testUser002",
         "product_ID":"475ggdfghghg"
      },
      {  
         "user_name":"testUser003",
         "product_ID":"47466gdgbdhg"
      },
      {  
         "user_name":"testUser004",
         "product_ID":"4000nfaergeb"
      },
      {  
         "user_name":"testUser005",
         "product_ID":"adfer73abdhg"
      }
   ]
}
```

Basic PHP code used to generate desired JSON (among sql query and other things):

```
$res = array();
$res2 = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)) {
    $res["user_name"] = $r["user_name"];
    $res["product_ID"] = $r["prod_ID"];
    array_push($res2,$res);


}


$response = ['pageNr' => $page];
$response = ['totalPages' => $totalPages];
$response = ['products' => $res2];
```

Response that this code is generating on Postman:

```
{  
   "products":[  
      {  
         "user_name":"testUser001",
         "product_ID":"4756373abdhg"
      },
      {  
         "user_name":"testUser002",
         "product_ID":"475ggdfghghg"
      },
      {  
         "user_name":"testUser003",
         "product_ID":"47466gdgbdhg"
      },
      {  
         "user_name":"testUser004",
         "product_ID":"4000nfaergeb"
      },
      {  
         "user_name":"testUser005",
         "product_ID":"adfer73abdhg"
      }
   ]
}
```

So, for some reason the JSON response is not accepting more fields `pageNr`and `totalPages`.

What is wrong here?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each assignment overwrites your array. You need to update it instead:

```
$res = array();
$res2 = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)) {
    $res["user_name"] = $r["user_name"];
    $res["product_ID"] = $r["prod_ID"];
    array_push($res2,$res);


}

$response = [];
$response['pageNr'] = $page;
$response['totalPages'] = $totalPages;
$response['products'] = $res2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try;

```
$res = array();
$res2 = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)) {
    $res["user_name"] = $r["user_name"];
    $res["product_ID"] = $r["prod_ID"];
    array_push($res2,$res);


}


$response .= ['pageNr' => $page];
$response .= ['totalPages' => $totalPages];
$response .= ['products' => $res2];
```